# 404 not found in telnet, works fine in browser

Tags: python, c, http, telnet

i am having a very irritating problem, when i open a url ( http://celebs.widewallpapers.net/md/a/adriana-lima/1440/Adriana-Lima-1440x900-002.jpg ) in browser, it works fine.. but when i try to access it by telnet on bash, i get 404 not found!!

my exact terminal:

$ telnet celebs.widewallpapers.net 80

HEAD /md/a/adriana-lima/1440/Adriana-Lima-1440x900-002.jpg HTTP/1.0
[enter]
[enter]

HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found

Server: nginx

Date: Sun, 23 May 2010 21:36:05 GMT

Content-Type: text/html; charset=windows-1251

Content-Length: 166
Connection: close

please help me with this as i m trying to make a C batch-downloader, which is almost working as same as the telnet.

Comment: The answer provided by calmh is probably correct, but you can use `wireshark` and/or tcpdump to capture both transactions (with telnet and with browser) and then examine how they differ.  There will likely be lots of things that the browser sends that aren't necessary or even accurate for your telnet version, but there will be things that are needed.  You may also want to look into the tools `wget` (web get), `curl` (copy URL), and `nc` (network cat).  Telnet may send some terminal setup stuff before it goes into pass through mode.

Comment: Why does this have a python tag?

Comment: @puddingfox
Probably to generate views. Some admin should take that off, though.

Answer (score 10):

You aren't passing a host header. As per HTTP/1.1 you need to tell the web server which virtual host you are expecting to talk to. And 99% of servers today will only talk HTTP/1.1 even if you specify HTTP/1.0 in the request.

```
jb@apto % telnet celebs.widewallpapers.net 80
...
HEAD /md/a/adriana-lima/1440/Adriana-Lima-1440x900-002.jpg HTTP/1.1
Host: celebs.widewallpapers.net

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Sun, 23 May 2010 22:08:36 GMT
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Connection: close
Last-Modified: Sun, 27 Apr 2008 14:30:17 GMT
ETag: "4784e0-264b0-48148df9"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 156848

Connection closed by foreign host.
```